# How do you create a round navigation system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a round navigation system, similar to the round nav button on an iPod Touch (see image here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/37476174@N06/4668497237/).

It needs to be JavaScript-based (not Flash). It would have different menu items around the dial. It also needs to be small (around 300px in diameter). Does such a JavaScript component already exist? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a couple of examples that may help: [CSSPlay](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/circular-sub.html) and [Fish Eye navigation](http://www.jampmark.com/html+css-techniques-demos/pure-css-fish-eye-menu-demo.html#expandDown) and [Circular navigation](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularPortfolio/)

Having said all this I've never played on an ipod enough to remember how it's done!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. In modern browsers that support CSS rounded corners, you could probably do it without any additional image files, but you could also have a simple circular image as a background. Then you'd position some clickable elements with transparent backgrounds and white/black/purple/whatever text for the buttons.

Mouse drag around the circle would be possible and a fun project but probably not trivial (mouse dragging always has some quirks.)

I've never seen a jQuery plugin for such a thing but I wouldn't be surprised if one exists. However, if it's just clickables around a circle, that wouldn't be too hard.  Javascript supports all the trig functions you'd need.